# Sending data to php via URL, with different amounts of variables

Tags: php, objective-c

I have a .php file that takes some information from the parameters in its URL.  This was working fine until I realized that each time I called the URL, there would be a different amount of variables.

Example:

`www.myurl.com/webserivce?var1=20&var2=30`

`www.myurl.com/webserivce?var1=20&var2=30&var3=40`

If I have 3 variables in my .php file, and only send the URL with 2, it crashes.

One potential work around is that I have 3 variables, and only send 1, I could fill the other 2 with 'NULL' or something like that:
`www.myurl.com/webserivce?var1=20&var2=NULL&var3=NULL`

I was just wondering if there was a better way.

BTW I am sending this URL request from an iOS app.

Comment: You could always write your PHP to check to see if the variables are set, and to use an empty value if they're not.

Comment: in php you can declare predefined variables values in your methods:
`function example($param1, $param2 = "", $param3 = null) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is your friend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). You're probably not checking to see if the variables are set and trying to do things with them hence resulting in a crash due to an access on a NULL variable.

Comment: so in .php, it is okay to send a url with insufficient amount of arguments, as long as I set them in my .php script ?

Comment: @HelloWorld As long as you don't try to access those arguments in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a POST instead and send along a structured data format?

You could construct a JSON object easily in Obj-C, send that, and then decode it in PHP. It will be much more flexible.

Comment: would this allow me to send varying amounts of parameters ?

Comment: Yes. You would construct an array in Obj-C, for example, which would get converted to a JSON representation of an array, and then decode it back to an array in PHP.

Comment: after looking into JSON, this is what I will use

Answer (score 0):

you can set the variables to null in the php script:

```
if(!isset($_GET['var1'])) $_GET['var1']="NULL";
if(!isset($_GET['var2'])) $_GET['var2']="NULL";
if(!isset($_GET['var3'])) $_GET['var3']="NULL";
```

Therefore, sending www.myurl.com/webserivce?var1=20&var2=30 would be the same as www.myurl.com/webserivce?var1=20&var2=30&var3=NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way it is pre-initialization all variables in your web-service